# Bootstrap x-editable combodate

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, x-editable

I've been playing a bit with X-editable for Bootstrap lately.
I am programming a webpage which displays data from a MySQL database. When I click on a button, I want all my data to become editable. When I click on save, the page automatically saves the changes in MySQL.

I have successfully programmed this for text fields and lists. But I can't make it work with dates. Perhaps someone has an idea that can help me?

Here is an example of the part that works:

```
<li id="f-name"><span>Name</span><a href="#" data-type="text" data-pk="1">John</a></li>
```

I use the following code to call the editable

```
$('#f-name').children('a').editable({
        placement: 'bottom'
    });
```

And I can use jQuery to get the value (after modification) with this code

```
var $val=$('#f-name').children('a').html();
```

Until this point, the code works well. But now let's see the part that doesn't work:

```
<li id="f-date"><span>Date: </span><a href="#" data-type="combodate" data-value="30 Apr 2016" data-format="DD MMM YYYY" data-viewformat="DD MMM YYYY" data-template="DD MMM YYYY" data-pk="1"></a></li>
```

I call the editable using:

```
$('#f-date').children('a').editable({
    placement: 'bottom',
});
```

I've tried using the same `$('#f-date').children('a').html();` code as before, but it didn't work. If I print it, it says `Undefined`. I don't really understand.
If I look in the Google Chrome code inspector (after the editable has been used), I get the following:

```
<a href="#" data-type="combodate" data-value="" data-format="DD MMM YYYY" data-viewformat="DD MMM YYYY" data-template="DD MMM YYYY" data-pk="1" class="editable editable-click editable-unsaved" data-original-title="" title="" style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">17 Jan 1999</a>
```

So I think it should work. How should I proceed?

Thanks for your help!

Best regards,
Yann

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `$('#f-date').find('a').text();` to retrieve the value as text.

Check this example

https://jsfiddle.net/wfeog8mc/

You can also use `params.newValue` to get the value from the x-editable event but I now that I look at it, it may not be UNIX timestamp...

Comment: The params.newValue works perfect for me. I just had to convert the timestamp to a more readable format.
Thanks for your answer, it was very valuable:)

Comment: Oh great. When I converted it online, it showed some large year. But if I remove the last 3 zeroes it works fine. Could be the converter i'm using.

Comment: Yes indeed the timestamp provided by params.newValue is in miliseconds. I first had to convert it in seconds by dividing it by 1000 so I could work with it. I found some converters online that accepted the miliseconds timestamp, and others did not.